# Disabled app notifications getting automatically re-enabled

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notifications, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3.

There's an app I use frequently, but don't want notifications from. Under "App info" I unchecked "Show notifications", and initially this does dismiss the app's notifications. After a few days, I get a notification from the app. Returning to the "App info" page I find that "Show notifications" has become checked again.

It's happened about 5 times in the last month, using the app a couple times per day. Automatic updates are disabled, and I have not updated the app recently. I've checked and verified that notifications do not get re-enabled every time I launch the app, or after a reboot, but otherwise I'm not sure what specific condition precipitates it. The app crashes occasionally on startup, but I don't know if this correlates to notifications getting turned out, especially as the app only sends occasional notifications, imploring me to use it more.

Is there a way to prevent notifications for this app from getting re-enabled?

**EDIT**: It seems to be getting re-enabled every time I reboot. Will test further to see if  I can reproduce it with other apps.

Comment: What app is it?

Comment: Subway Surfers.

Comment: May have something to do with the app crashing. Do you have any log info as to why it is crashing?

Comment: The phone is not rooted. Can I collect any useful log info?

Comment: If an app force closes you can choose to preview and save crash info before sending it to the developer. There may be something in there that will help us out

Comment: I have the same issue (my son loves the app), and thought I'd add that I've not seen the app crash on my S4, so don't think that's the cause.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on my Galaxy S3.  Maybe a Samsung-created bug? I started a bug report on the Android Open Source Issue Tracker.  If this is still a problem for anyone reading this, please star it on the issue tracker to get it more attention.  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75544

Comment: Maybe "Show notifications" gets re-enabled every time Subway Surfers does an update! and it does update so often :)

Comment: I can confirm that a crash very often resets the settings in a program both on PC and Android.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution that worked for me. When 4.3 came out the first thing i did was place all my apps on the SD card which was great for freeing up space on the phone. Unfort. all app notification settings reset upon reboot as you described which was super frustrating. Specifically i'm talking about the app notification check box you see in every app when in android settings. I took 2 games in particular that kept waking me up at night with notifications and moved them back to phone storage which fixed the problem. Did 2 reboots in a row and it worked perfectly. Boxes are still unchecked

Hope this helps.

Source : [Android Central](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/345112-default-apps-reset-notifications-start-happening-after-reboot.html)

Comment: This was a bug in Samsung's 4.3 ROM and SD card issue. +1 for this. Also worth noting, many apps have a notifications option within the app itself that can be disabled, rather than going through the `Settings>Applications` route.