# Can anyone confirm updates to an application are what causes the notifications to turn back on?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, updates, notifications, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have turned off all notifications in Android 5.1.1 (although from my research, it doesn't appear to be limited to that OS- 4.3 and up at least). It appears every time I update the app, it resets the notifications to "on." Which is only mostly annoying at 1am. :/ I can confirm it isn't a reboot, and mine is not related to crashes of the apps themselves. I have run some brief tests to confirm it's the update, but don't have enough data to confidently say it's the update. Anyone? Related: Does anyone know if Marshmallow's (6.x) "specific app permissions" alleviate this problem? Thanking you all in advance!

Comment: No, doesn't happen here, and I didn't update the app using Play Store but sideloaded it on Android 5.0.2 or 5.1.1. What device are you using?

Comment: I'm going to guess that it is an Amazon app? Either the Kindle app or the shopping? I have turned off notifications to many times, and find it restored later, and it occurs to me that the recent update probably flipped the switch (again). Please supply the specific app name if this assumption proves false.

Comment: Related on Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/68931/disabled-app-notifications-getting-automatically-re-enabled, and on AOSP Issue Tracker [#75544](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75544)

Answer (score -1):

This depends on whether or not the application is replaced, or simply updated. If you do it through the Play Store, it will likely reset the notification settings. If you were to install it through other means (such as adb install) then it depends on whether or not the original application was 'updated' or re-installed

Comment: Please don't post untested answers. You've left everything on probability here: a) "*it will likely reset the notification settings*" -- would or would not, preferred is would, but not confirmed. b) "*then it depends on whether or not the original application was 'updated' or re-installed*" -- again, no concrete evidence. What would it be: for update or for re-installed? And why would it be any different from update from Play Store?